# wifi connections not showing up in newly dual booted ubuntu 16.04.03

Tags: dual-boot, wireless, internet, realtek-wireless, additional-drivers

I have freshly installed ubuntu 16.04.03 along side of windows 10 in my HPbs542tu laptop, i am able to connect to internet using usb tethering but it is not showing up wifi connections, noidea is wifi is off or not.
Am struck, any one here can help me out??

```
    ~$ sudo lshw -class network

  `*-network UNCLAIMED     
       description: Ethernet controller
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: 15
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: ioport:4000(size=256) memory:b1104000-b1104fff memory:b1100000-b1103fff
  *-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Network controller
       product: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: ioport:3000(size=256) memory:b1000000-b100ffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 3
       logical name: enp0s20f0u3
       serial: 3e:aa:92:04:06:bd
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rndis_host driverversion=22-Aug-2005 firmware=RNDIS device ip=xx.xx.xx.xx link=yes multicast=yes`

=======================================================================

`~$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 05c8:03ac Cheng Uei Precision Industry Co., Ltd (Foxlink) 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0bda:b009 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 1ebf:6880  
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub`


    ===================================================================

`~$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Sky Lake Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 08)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Sky Lake Integrated Graphics (rev 07)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Skylake Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 08)
00:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Sky Lake Gaussian Mixture Model
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 21)
00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Thermal subsystem (rev 21)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP CSME HECI (rev 21)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 21)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port (rev f1)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port (rev f1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP LPC Controller (rev 21)
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PMC (rev 21)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio (rev 21)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SMBus (rev 21)
01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)
02:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device d723`

==================================================================
`~$ rfkill list all
1: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no`
```

Comment: Disable Secure Boot at UEFI.

Comment: I already done that.... It been one week i have trued many solutions... Still not working....

Comment: Default driver for eno1 was e1000 so i have compiled and installed 8168 driver successful and blacklisted 8169. On lsmod |grep 8168 it was showing up. But I didn't get exact step on how to change my interface name to eno1.... Some body please tell me that. After a reboot the driver is set back to e1000 why is that? I am fed up with this... Please help